# I am seeing jQueryXXX="YY" attributes added to some of my DOM elements

Tags: jquery

When I use the IE developer tools, some of the DOM elements have attributes added that are of the form
   jQueryXXXXXXXXX="YY"
where XXXXX is a fairly long digit string and YY is a usually small integer value.

I don't see these with the DOM inspector on Safari.

Why and when are these added? Is the data useful to me in any way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the jQuery [expando attribute](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L10), it's a key on the object used to find it's entry in `$.cache`.  `$.cache` is used for [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), event handlers, or anything you want to stick in there, it's a centralized place to store events (makes firing global events easier/more efficient as well) and one place for cleanup.  By carrying only the attribute on the element, it's not necessary to have a data store on *each* element which may not clone correctly-cross browser, rather it only maintains this key, and can lookup it's entry in the `$.cache` object at any point.

Let's take an example:

```
domElement[$.expando] //only works in 1.4+, expando was private previously
```

This will give an "ID" or key of sorts, that key corresponds to the property on the [`$.cache`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L4) object that stores this element's data/events (*if* it has any data/event handlers).  For example if the key was "4", it would be used internally to access `$.cache[4]`.

`$.cache` contains all data, event handlers, etc for all elements that were assigned by jQuery.  It's assigned by incrementing the [`$.uuid`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L7) (an internal ever climbing ID jquery assigns and increments any time a *new* object's added into `$.cache`).

---

*A few extra bits:*

The random nature of the name isn't all that random, the `jQueryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` is [just `jQuery` + the timestamp then jquery was loaded](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L10), to give the attribute a unique hopefully non-colliding name.

Why don't you see it with `.html()`?, well because [jQuery hides it](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L228), it does a [regex to strip it out](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/manipulation.js#L1).

*Note:* `$.expando` isn't exposed in 1.3, only 1.4+.

---

*Usage:*

Is it useful?  Well it can be, for example if you analyze `$.cache` in your console, and you see you have a memory leak (no [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) before many [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) calls, leaving event handlers behind for example).  You open your console, and do `$.cache`, you see 500 entries there, let's say you want to know which object went with 312, then you can select it, like this:

```
$("[" + $.expando + "=312]")[0] //DOM element for this entry
```

As another example, this:

```
$("#myElem").data('events') //get events object, equivalent to:
$.cache[$("#myElem")[0][$.expando]].events
```

This is one example that's handy, typically the average jQuery user does't need to dive into `$.cache` or how it works, but it is there and available in case you never need to go looking.  Just run `$.cache` in your console, there's likely a wealth of information about all your handlers that you didn't know was available :)

Comment: I noticed this too, so due to the expando the statements about jQuery not really manipulating your element ( adding custom attributes ) are false, obviously.

Comment: @meder - It adds one *property* yes, that's not the same as an attribute, attribute ~= property in terms of the DOM, but they're not exactly equivalent.  Also, this only happens when you use jQuery to add an event or data, it doesn't by default add any properties to all your elements :)

Comment: very articulate response. Thank you for taking the time to address.