# jQuery and weird links in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm working on a website and part of it's code (jQuery related) was written by another programmer. Now in IE7 some links look like this (at least that's what Developer Tools shows me):

```
<a href="#" id="id1" jQuery1284452043889="13">some link</a>
<a href="#" id="id2" jQuery1284452043889="14">some link</a>
```

I'm not good at JS, so could you please tell me what those additional jQuery attributes mean? What are they needed for?

Thank you!

Comment: I have never seen any attributes as defined above. Most probably the developer might be using some jquery plug-in that is responsible for generating those attributes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am seeing jQueryXXX="YY" attributes added to some of my DOM elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336672/i-am-seeing-jqueryxxxyy-attributes-added-to-some-of-my-dom-elements)

Comment: Sorry, didn't find that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a jQuery Expando attribute.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336672/i-am-seeing-jqueryxxxyy-attributes-added-to-some-of-my-dom-elements) explains it quite nicely

Comment: Good find! It's really a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yeah, My google searches included 'jqueryxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'jqueryx', 'jqueryxx' and 'jqueryxxx'. Agreed its a dumplicate, so have voted to close.

Answer (score -1):

Thats simply jQuery making its presence felt, nothing you as a regular developer should either worry or care about.